# Keeping two sorted vectors linked by pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

(yes it is a homework)

I am trying to create a simple database where a person is identified by a name + address combination or by an unique account number. I need to be able to quickly add/delete/access information about a person when provided an acc number or the name + addr.

I have created a version that works without the account (using overloaded operator < for searching in the database with lower_bound), now I am trying to add the account feature.

Here is what I've got:

```
struct SPerson
{
    string s_name, s_addr;
    int s_income, s_expense;
    SAccount * s_accountPtr;

    SPerson ( const string &, const string & );  // constructor
};

struct SAccount
{
    string s_account;
    SPerson * s_personPtr;

    SPerson ( const string & );   // constructor
};
```

The idea is to have a vector of accounts and a vector of people and keeping them linked with pointers. Seemed simple until I came across these questions:

- If I create an object and insert it into a vector, does a copy of that object get created and inserted? Or is it the original object?
- What happens with the addresses of objects in a vector when I insert something into it?
- Can I even make this work somehow?

  ```
  bool CDatabase::Birth ( const string & name, const string & addr, const string & account )
  {

      SPerson personToAdd = SPerson ( name, addr );
      SAccount accountToAdd = SAccount ( account );

      SPiter = lower_bound ( SPeople.begin ( ), SPeople.end ( ), personToAdd );
      SAiter = lower_bound ( SAccounts.begin ( ), SAccounts.end ( ), AccountToAdd );

      if ( ( SPiter -> s_name == name &&
         SPiter -> s_addr == addr ) ||
         SAiter -> s_account == account ) return false;

      personToAdd.s_accountPtr = & accountToAdd;   // this is proabably very wrong
      accoutToAdd.s_personPtr = & personToAdd;

      SPeople.insert ( SPiter, personToAdd );   // does this mess up the pointers?
      SAccounts.insert ( SAiter, accountToAdd );

      return true;
  ```

  }

// I am sorry the code formatting is killing me, gonna fix asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`If I create an object and insert it into a vector, does a copy of that object get created and inserted? Or is it the original object?`

If you use `push_back` or `insert` then a copy is made. If you don't want a copy use `emplace_back`. Inserting elements anywhere other than the end of a vector is inefficient since it will move all the elements after the insertion point or worse all elements.

`What happens with the addresses of objects in a vector when I insert something into it?`

They might or might not change depending on the size of the vector and where you insert. So having raw pointers to vector elements is probably a bad idea. As soon as you insert something in the middle or the vector grows beyond its capacity all your pointers might point to nonsense.

`Can I even make this work somehow?`

Yes, just use handles instead of raw pointers. And if you are allowed use different data structures like `std::map` `std::unordered_set` to retrieve accounts/persons instead of having to go through a vector and compare handles.

Comment: Thanks. That is basically what I thought (what made the biggest sense) and the only thing I am allowed to use from STL is vector. I hear 'handle' for the first time, so I guess I am going to google a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're trying to accomplish some sort of `relationship` between `SAccount` and `SPerson` more specifically an `one-to-one` relationship So, I recommend you to simulate the actual behaviour of a database system.

You can have you `SAccount` class like this:

```
struct SAccount
{
    string s_account;
    int person_id;            // Since id is unique.

    SAccount ( const int );   // constructor
};
```

That way each `account` holds the `id` of a person.

**Edit: UPDATE**

```
struct SPerson
{
    static id=0;
    string s_name, s_addr;
    int s_income, s_expense;
    int pid, account_id;
    SPerson ( const string &, const string & , int account_id, person_id=++Sperson::id);  // constructor
};

struct SAccount
{
    static id=0;
    string s_account;
    int aid, person_id;
        SPerson ( const string & , int person_id, int account_id=++SAccount::id);   // constructor
};
```

With the static attributes you care about automatic id generation.

Comment: I am thousand times sorry. I used the word 'ID' in the text and the 'account' in the code but they are the same. A person is identified by their account.

Comment: It's the same. Just add an `perons_id` attribute to `SAccount` and a `account_id` attribute to `SPerson`.

Comment: Answer updated. The new classes handles the automatic id generration for you. An account has a person_id, and a person has an account id. So you can search in respective vectors by the id of the objects. Hope this helps. It's a kind og "virtual linking" :D

Comment: Thanks but I still don't quite understand - this approach does get me the desired "link" between those two structs, what I actually aim for is to have two sorted vectors and to be able to access the Account given the Person information and vice versa without having to search for it linearly (for that, I don't need the id at all). I am sorry if I am overcomplicating this I just... am getting lost

Answer (score 0):

One, simple solution would be to keep pointers to persons and accounts in your vectors. Even if this implies some more caution when implementing the data base, it could greatly ease the design and the performance for inserting and deleting objects from the vector.

And now a thousand people will argue, that one have to use at least reference counting smart pointers, I would still argue against them in this particular situation :-).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to thank you for your answers (once again on SO, I found out about a million new things by asking a primitive question) but I decided not to use any of the solutions - I went for this:

I keep the SPeople vector sorted and each time I insert a new person there, I also insert a new account to SAccounts under the same index (therefore, this one is not sorted). That way, I can access an account when given the person info in O(log n). The other way, given the account info, the search is linear, but I've been told that linear search is still fast enough for this.

I have some problems implementing the system mentioned above, however that is not a subject of this question and I will post another question to discuss that. :)